# Storing the result set in array while fetching from db in java?

Tags: java, arrays, json, list, hashmap

This is what I am getting from  db in column name

```
                          data
                  CLONE,CREATE,DELETE
```

I want to store in array something like this in a array

```
                    [CLONE,CREATE,DELETE]
```

This is what I am trying but output comes in normal JSON something like this

```
"clone ,create ,delete"
```

My code is something like this

```
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            ResultSet rs = RetrieveData();
            while (rs.next()) {
                JSONObject record = new JSONObject();
                record.put("permissionType", rs.getString("data"));
                array.put(record);
            }
            jsonObject.put("JSON_OBJECT", array);
            try {
                System.out.println(jsonObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to look at doing something like `rs.getString("data").split(",")`, which will return an array of Strings split using a comma i.e. `["clone", "create", "delete"]`